# Can not match forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot seem to get the GET A QUOTE forms the same.
I want the form on the homepage to look the same as the one on fleet.html
They have the same exact code.
The form on the homepage is in the bottom left of the page.

http://demo.cipslimoshuttle.com/

http://demo.cipslimoshuttle.com/fleet.html

Comment: and what do you expect SO users to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a reference to jquery.jqtransform.js in the root site HTML and also no code to actually do the transformation from standard controls to the pretty jqTransform controls.

So, adding

```
<script src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jqtransform.css">
```

to the head, and changing the `ready` code to

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.camera_wrap').camera();
    $('#form-2').jqTransform({imgPath:'../images/'});
    });
</script>
```

will fix it. (It does when I do it via the Developer console!)